# Probability distribution of a sum of dependant random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Firstly I have very littly stats knowledge so I apology if this ends up being a very straight forward question.

If $a$ and $b$ are uniform random variables from $0$ to $1$. Then what is the probability distribution function of $z=a+a^2 b$. I assume I can't use convolution as $a$ and $a^2b$ are dependant.  Also how would I calculate the joint diatrubition of $a$ and $a^2b $, which i think i'd need to calculate the pdf of $z$

Comment: Luckily for you, $a$ and $1+b$ are independent. :)

Comment: Ah. Thanks :).  If that weren't the case like the now edited question, any ideas.